# Using multiprocessing with opencv python Face recognition system

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, multiprocessing

The below code is responsible for continuous face recognition system under live stream feed and using a wake up word for communication the aim is to run the main() function and get_input() function in multiprocess to fasten the execution time as it lags upon running with threads.

```py
import cv2
from simple_facerec import SimpleFacerec
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import ExtraMicrophone
import NameExtract
import pyaudio
import pvporcupine
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Event

class FaceRecognitionApp:
    def __init__(self):
        # self.known_face = "test"
        self.get_frame = False
        self.name_frame = ""
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
        self.known_names = []
        # Encode faces from a folder
        self.sfr = SimpleFacerec()
        self.sfr.load_encoding_images("images/")
        self.reply_message = ""
        self.detection = False
    def capture_and_save_screenshot(self, frame, filename):
        # Create a copy of the frame to avoid modifying the original frame
        frame_copy = frame.copy()

        # Detect Faces
        face_locations, face_names = self.sfr.detect_known_faces(frame_copy)
        for face_loc, name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = face_loc[0], face_loc[1], face_loc[2], face_loc[3]

            # Draw rectangles on the copy of the frame
            cv2.rectangle(frame_copy, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 200), 4)

        # Save the copy without rectangles
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame_copy)

    def main(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            # Detect Faces
            face_locations, face_names = self.sfr.detect_known_faces(frame)
            for face_loc, name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
                y1, x2, y2, x1 = face_loc[0], face_loc[1], face_loc[2], face_loc[3]

                cv2.putText(frame, name, (x1, y1 - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 200), 2)
                # self.known_face = name
                self.known_names = face_names
            # Check if get_frame is True and capture a screenshot
            # print(self.known_names)
            if self.get_frame:
                self.capture_and_save_screenshot(frame, f"images/{self.name_frame}.jpg")
                self.get_frame = False

            cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key == ord('q'):
                break
            elif key == ord('s'):
                self.get_frame = True

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def get_input(self):
        while True:
            self.detection = False
            keyword_path = 'C:/Users/WOB/Desktop/WOB-Robo-Code-main/RoboAppApplication/HeySam.ppn'
            access_key = 'zBapjwgbd0M1f7jDBHxkKG52DLToh8gCLuo06ffIom43uhFNJhLPpw=='
            print("Entered stop check")

            def audio_callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
                # global detection
                pcm = np.frombuffer(in_data, dtype=np.int16)
                keyword_index = handle.process(pcm)
                if keyword_index >= 0:
                    self.detection = True
                    print("Keyword Detected!")

                return None, pyaudio.paContinue

            print("1")

            handle = pvporcupine.create(keyword_paths=[keyword_path], access_key=access_key)

            pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

            audio_stream = pa.open(
                rate=handle.sample_rate,
                channels=1,
                format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=handle.frame_length,
                stream_callback=audio_callback
            )

            audio_stream.start_stream()
            print("2")
            while not self.detection:
                pass

            audio_stream.stop_stream()
            audio_stream.close()

            pa.terminate()
            print("3")
            
            # msg = ExtraMicrophone.stt('en-US')
            # if msg == "hello":
            print(self.known_names)
            if len(self.known_names)>1:
                for n in self.known_names:
                    count_unknown = self.known_names.count('Unknown')
                    new_known_list = [item for item in self.known_names if item != 'Unknown']
                    for n in new_known_list:
                        self.reply_message += f"{n},"
                    if count_unknown >=2: 
                        self.reply_message+= "and there are people i don't know. I will get to know you when we speak alone."
                    elif count_unknown == 1:
                        self.reply_message += "and there is one person i don't know.I will get to know you when we speak alone."
            elif len(self.known_names)==1:
                if self.known_names[0]=="Unknown":
                    self.reply_message = "Hey there, what is your name"
                    print(self.reply_message)
                    while len(self.name_frame)<=0:
                        msg = ExtraMicrophone.stt('en-US')
                        self.name_frame = NameExtract.get_name(msg,"en-US")
                        print(self.name_frame)
                    self.get_frame = True
            else:
                self.reply_message = "How are you"
            print("Hello", self.reply_message)

    def run(self):
        exit_event = Event()
        p_main = Process(target=self.main)
        p_input = Process(target=self.get_input, args=(exit_event,))

        p_main.start()
        p_input.start()

        try:
            p_main.join()
            p_input.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit_event.set()
            p_main.join()
            p_input.join()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = FaceRecognitionApp()
    # app.executor.submit(app.main)
    # app.executor.submit(app.get_input)
    app.run()
```

this is the method that I tried to use using multiprocessing but it didn't work any ideas how can I use the multiprocessing.

I tried using threads and threadpool executor. In addtion to a simple Multiprocess code which uses target and start but  i faced errors in Queuing.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).